# SDK and DLL files for SUPREMA Biolite net

Tags: dll, sdk

I want to connect my Java application with the fingerprint reader **Suprema BioLite Net**, but I do not find the SDK and DLL files for this product, can you please help me.

Comment: Are you find a solution to connect to biolite net from java?